# Prime Zeta without Möbius Function and Prime Summation

Tags: summation, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions, mobius-function

The prime zeta function can be expressed inversely in terms of the Riemann zeta function:

$$P(s)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(k)}{k} \ln[\zeta(ks)]$$

The equation is defined [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeZetaFunction.html). The Mathworld page also defines other ways it can be expressed in terms of the Riemann Zeta function, but they are expressed where $\ln[\zeta(s)] = \mathrm{etc}$, not $P(s)=\mathrm{etc}$.

Can this be rewritten to not use the Möbius ($\mu$) Function and without prime summation ($\sum_{p}$)?

---

I am using this in a C++ program. I am using the Boost libraries, so I can use the zeta function (but Boost does not have the *prime* zeta function). It also does not have the Mobius function. This is why I cannot really use the Mobius function like in the equation above.

As well, to use prime summation (or similarly product of primes), I have to generate a large vector of primes (not optimal). This is why I cannot really use prime summation (or product of primes, I suppose).

Comment: Your question means nothing. By the way, do you know how to prove this formula ?

Comment: @user1952009 I am not out to prove it. I will update the question to provide a link to the Mathworld page where it is defined.

Comment: You wouldn't have any hope to make it simpler, if you knew how to prove it

Comment: Which operations do you allow?

Comment: @user1952009 **Thus why I ask it here**, I have no idea how to redefine it without the Mobius function or prime summation, I was hoping someone here could be helpful.

Comment: @Charles Everything but Mobius and prime summation, like the question says.

Comment: @Anonymous In that case the answer is yes, just set $P(s)=P(s)$ since $P$ is not the Moebius function and you're not using any sums, prime or otherwise.

Comment: @Charles Haha, okay. I will update my question to specify my use case so it is clearer why I cannot use the Mobius function and prime summation.

Comment: @Anonymous Thanks! Yes, it's a silly way for me to explain it but without knowing what limits you are under I can't write a reasonable answer.

Comment: What you need to prove is that $\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} = \prod_p (1+\sum_{k \ge 1} p^{-sk}) = \prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}} $ $ \implies \ln \zeta(s) = -\sum_p \ln(1-p^{-s}) = \sum_p \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{p^{-sm}}{m}$ $ \implies \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(k)}{k} \ln \zeta(sk)= \sum_p p^{-s}$

Comment: There is no simple formula for those complicated functions, and if you don't understand why, it means you have no good reason to evaluate $P(s)$ in a C++ program.

Comment: @user1952009 I am not great at math, I have no idea how to do this. I am sorry if this is not sufficient enough for you. I wish I could do that, but I am not in college, I wish I was. Regarding your second comment: I was just having fun creating a program to calculate a constant that happens to use the prime zeta function.

Comment: This is a maths forum. If you want a formula that you don't understand, this is not the good place.

Comment: @user1952009 From the Mathematics Stack Exchange Tour page: "Mathematics Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for people studying math at any level" - the first paragraph. I suppose they should change the tour page if that isn't true anymore.

Comment: Studying maths doesn't mean playing with formulas. It means understanding where those formulas come form, how and why to use them,  etc. And see this [very simple implementation of $\mu(k),k < N$](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/99473/calculating-m%C3%B6bius-function/227408#227408) (and try to understand why it works)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your question seems to be: how can you program the prime zeta function in C++?

The easiest way would be to use an existing implementation in C++ or C. For example, I have one here
[PARI-extensions](https://github.com/CRGreathouse/PARI-extensions/blob/69c72d1c6da659ad92966c28a37e5c24be1c4e31/rc.gp.c#L5)
using the [PARI](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) library.

If you would prefer to write your own version using Boost, then you could re-implement my code (you'll probably want the `primezeta_real` function) using Boost instead of the PARI library. You would also need to write the Lambert W function, but that is not difficult and doesn't need to be done with high precision (it's used to determine how long you need to iterate a loop).

If you want to do a better job, you should read Cohen's [High precision computation of Hardy-Littlewood constants](http://www.math.u-bordeaux1.fr/~cohen/hardylw.dvi) which explains an efficient method. But the paper would be hard to follow for someone without a math background.

Comment: And  $\sum_{k < x} \frac{\mu(k)}{k}\ln \zeta(sk)$ is a good approximation to $P(s)$, since $\ln \zeta(sk) = \mathcal{O}(2^{-k})$ (and in the code it seems it is computing $\mu(k)$ each $k$ separately, which is not a good idea)

Comment: Charles, thanks, your code is incredibly helpful. I am not sure if anyone else will be helpful, so I really appreciate it. I happen to have the Lambert W function programmed in C++ with arbitrary precision (it was really fun to code). With all my searching I can't believe I haven't heard of the PARI library!

Comment: @Anonymous I'm glad it was useful! Yes, you should look into PARI/GP, it's very useful. In fairness, as user1952009 points out, my code is not terribly efficient -- with a sieve you could find the mu values faster. But if you're just using float or double precision it shouldn't be bad unless you're using arguments smaller than 1.